# Why do RGB colors form a pyramid when plotted in 3D space?

Tags: python, plotly, cluster-analysis, rgb, graphing

I wanted to plot the pixels of this photograph in 3D space, with x=red, y=green, z=blue.

[image: tulips]

When I do that, I get this strange pyramid shape, when I expected the volume of the cube formed by the xyz axes to be more uniformly filled in.

[image]

Is this expected behavior for rgb plots when plotted in Cartesian space?

Comment: Your colors in this picture aren't uniform, so why would your graph be uniform?

Comment: For example, there's nothing blue, or anything close to blue, so that's a whole region of the color space that will have no points.

Comment: This is to be expected. RGB at its most elemental means R varies from 0 to 255, G varies from 0 to 255, B varies from 0 to 255. In cartesian space, these are being plotted as x,y, and z. This means coordinates vary from (0,0,0) to (255,255,255) and all combinations in between depending on the colors in the graphic. For example RED = (255,0,0) etc. Thus the pyramid shape is shown.

Comment: Because you have a picture, a standard picture. If you convert in black and white, you will not see much extremes. And photography usually expose to 50%-grey (ar 18% grey depending the scale you use). Go in a forest, to a photo of leaves and sky [so high dynamic rance], and you will see a much different figures (but you will lack much of bright red)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this seemed normal, as opposed to something buggy happening under the hood with my data. I should have been clearer: I didn't expect a uniform distribution, I just was confused by the hard edges of the shape.